# Creating a new user using System.Web.Providers within ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, system.web, createuser

I've been able to call `Membership.CreateUser` which has created the necessary Membership tables within my database, but it hasn't added the newly created user into the `Users` table and the `MembershipCreateStatus = InvalidAnswer` - not sure what this means.

```
public void Register(Register register)
        {
            var member = new System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider();
            object guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            MembershipCreateStatus status;

            member.CreateUser(register.Username, register.Password, "", "", "", true, guid, out status);

        }
```

Configuration:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: are you seeding users and roles?

Comment: Just realised the status is InvalidAnswer. I'm guessing that's because I've configured it so that it needs a password question and answer?

Comment: on creating user successfully it will assign `MembershipCreateStatus = Success`

Comment: I think I realised that. Do you know how to make it successful?

Comment: Have you checked after changing this `enablePasswordRetrieval="false"`  in `web.config` and also try changing like this ` member. `CreateUser(register.Username, register.Password, "an email address", null, null, true, guid, out status);`

Comment: Yes my config is above in the answer and it matches what you said. I'll try using null instead of ""

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24029/discussion-between-don-and-neeta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here are based on our discussion.

I assume that you have this specified this in your `web.config` as `enablePasswordRetrieval="false"` from your comment

Then this code will work for you

```
try
{
    object guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    MembershipCreateStatus status;
    MemberShipUser member = Membership.CreateUser(register.Username, register.Password, "an email address here", null, null, true, guid, out status);
}
catch(MembershipCreateUserException ex)
{
    //handle exceptions
}
```